# How to choose a variable depending on the index of a for loop

Tags: python, loops, iteration

I have the following lists

```
list_0=[]
list_1=[]
list_2=[]
```

I want to assign to each list a value in a for loop.
so that in the first iteration, I can assign a value to the list_0, by the second iteration , a value to the list_1 and so forth.
how can I do it ?

Thanks

Comment: have a list containing your lists  `bigList = [list_0, list_1, list_2]`. so in your loop you can iterate `i` and access each sublist as `bigList[i]`. You can then assign a value to the list_i  doing `bigList[i] = [1,2,3]`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I create variable variables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1373164/how-do-i-create-variable-variables)

Comment: @SembeiNorimaki better example than `bigList[i] = "foo"` might be `bigList[i].append("foo")`

Answer (score 1):

As highlighted in the comments you can make a biglist of your list e.g.

```
bigList = [list_0, list_1, list_2]
for i in range(3):
    my_list = biglist[i] # list according to i is fetched
```

Another approach i suggest to you is to make a dictionary

```
myList = {0: list_0, 1: list_1, 2: list_2}
for i in range(3):
    my_list = biglist[i] # list according to i is fetched
```